# NGINX redirects all pages to the default

Tags: nginx-config

I am using a NGINX Webserver for my websites, hosted on an Ubuntu 22.04. The domain *.testing.example.com is pointing on my webserver, since I keep deploying new websites on a regular basis.

I have several nginx configs pointing to websites like test.testing.example.com, test2.testing.example.com and so on. If I open up a website, where no config exists on the server to, it always puts up test.testing.example.com (the first config in the sites-enabled folder).

I tried to set up a default page. Something like this:

```
server {
        listen          80 default_server;
        server_name     _;
        root            /opt/nginx/html;

        location / {
        }
```

It works, but my other websites, test.testing.example.com, test2.testing.example.com also get redirected to the new default page now.

Is there any way I can prevent this in my Setup?